# UBUNTU EXT2 Partitionen

Tags: partitioning

english and german written,

I used windows partition manager to do away 2 ubuntu partitions or 1 ubuntu and 1 windows nt. I used "Delete Volume". What i didn't say is put it together with my working Ubuntu Partition but it did it and declared it as FAT32 in Windows.
On Ubuntu with Partition Managers it is visible as EXT2. There was no formatting of the 2 20 gb partitions. windows just putted it together.

I tried testdisk, gparted, and some others. With the explorer i can see only a directory from the windows partition as my UBUNTU so it doesn't show me my ubuntu it shows me what it declared to the new partition. i'm sure my data is still there but unpointed.

Does anybody know how to seperate these Partition without loosing data.

German.
Ich habe in Windows den partition manager benutzt um 2 ubuntu partitionen oder 1 ubuntu und 1 nt partition zu löschen. Benutzt habe ich "Volume löschen". Was er getan hat ist diese 2 Partitionen mit meiner funktionierenden UBUNTU Partition zusammenzuführen und als FAT32 Partition zu deklarieren.
AUF Ubuntu sieht man die FAT32 als EXT2 nur sind 2 20 GB Partitionen jetzt mit 100 GB 140 geworden und es gab kein formatieren der 2 Partitionen bevor sie unfreiwillig mit der 3ten zusammengelegt wurden.

Weiß jemand wie man diese 3 partitionen auseinanderführen kann oder sich für eine der 3 entscheidet in dem man sie browsable macht.

Thanks, Ciao Marko

Answer (score 0):

Just use **GParted** to shrink the Windows partition and then make a new partition in the freed space, again using **GParted**. Don't worry about lost data since you haven't used that space yet.